# deploy 24/7 running python app

Tags: linux, redhat, python, deployment

I want to deploy a Python app on Red-hat Linux which reads Kafka streams and pushes the data to some downstream processes.
What is the best way/practices to deploy/run my Python application so that it runs all the time in the background and restarts on startup?
The goal is to keep reading the Kafka streams and push the data continuously.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should create `.service` file for your application in `/etc/systemd/system` or in `/usr/lib/systemd/system` and enable it. Something like this:

```
[Unit]
Description=My script
After=network.target

[Service]
Type=simple
Restart=always
RestartSec=5
WorkingDirectory=/tmp
StartLimitInterval=0
StartLimitBurst=999999
User=myuser
Group=myuser
ExecStart=/path/to/my/executable/script

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

For example it would be `yourservice.service` file. Then execute `systemctl daemon-reload`, `systemctl enable yourservice.service` and `systemctl start yourservice.service`. This way suitable when you don't use `virtualenv`.

Comment: Thank You very much

Comment: @AsTi you could mark my answer as correct.

Answer (score 0):

You can configure uwsgi or gunicorn to run as as service, there should be examples on the web (I'm not adding one as they can be out of date pretty fast). If you have systemd on the server it migt